# In iOS, how would you programmatically pass a username / password to a secure site

Tags: ios

How can you, in iOS, programmatically access a password protected site that has been protected by .htaccess or access control.

Using NSURLRequest, you can make a GET request from a URL. But if the URL is protected how would you send the username password pair. Also, what if it's encrypted with standard MD5 encryption.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add something like this to your HTTPConnectionDelegate:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
        if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
                NSURLCredential *newCredential;
                newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:username password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
                [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        } else {
                [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks..Is this passed as clear text? Some webservers reject clear text passwords.

Comment: The docs aren't clear, but I'd have to guess that it uses the authentication method requested by the server.  If that's basic-auth, then it won't be encrypted (unless the connection is SSL).  If it's digest auth, then it will use the md5 one-way hashing method.