# Accessing Video Content ONLY through an iOS App - How would I do that

Tags: iphone, ios, video, youtube, video-streaming

I've got a client that wants to have a paid app providing his video instructional content on iOS, but of course we dont want people simply getting the video content directly without paying for the app.

Is there some simple way of doing this that I'm overlooking? He wants the content streamed so he can add content easily and periodically without app updates.

Perhaps using Youtube but having the videos password protected? Is there a service anyone has used with an appropriate iOS API that anyone has heard of?

Comment: It is fundamentally impossible to stop a determined person from pretending to be an iPad.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this before, but you could do some kind of token exchange based on the device ID. When the app is first used, register the device ID with the content server, and use that in combination with a salted hash of some kind to identify the device when requesting the media from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm considering two options right now.

1- Following this post (roughly) [In iOS, how would you programmatically pass a username / password to a secure site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589377/in-the-iphone-sdk-how-would-you-programatically-pass-a-username-password-to-a) and essentially doing a combination of .htaccess for password protection,  leveraging robots.txt to prevent search engines from indexing the videos, and obfuscating the video names. I've got to research the password protection of the video directory and how exactly to do that... but it seems the simplest. The downside is the clear text password.

2- A slightly more sophisticated method where I use oAuth to authenticate against but really following the first path, and  potentially leveraging http://maniacdev.com/2010/09/new-open-source-oauth-library-for-easy-authentication-on-ios-devices-from-google/  to help in writing the oAuth piece.

a third possibly prohibitively expensive option is to look at the HTTP live streaming in OSX server https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

How do you guys think these options sound? Are there others I'm not considering?